# ZipArchive not properly compressing files

Tags: php, zip, php-ziparchive

I have a php code which is creating a zip file and download the same. The below code is zipping the files on the php server however when I am trying to unzip the downloaded file at my local system, it is not unzipping the files and shoing the below error :

> Cannot open the file as [zip] Archive Is not archive.

Below is my code :

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));

$prefix = $filelist = '';
foreach($data as $d)
{
    $filelist .= $prefix . '"' . $d . '"';
    $prefix = ', ';
}

$files = $filelist;
$zipname = 'file45.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $zip->addFile($file);
}
$zip->close();

header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zipname);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
readfile($zipname);

?>
```

Any inputs would be highly useful

Comment: get rid of this `?>` and make sure you don't have any output,  such as error messages.  You can open the zip file as text, and you may see error messages in it.  Also why is `$filelist .= ` a string `$files = $filelist;` and `foreach ($files as $file)`

Comment: This line `foreach ($files as $file)` should give you _"Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"_ since `$files` is a string.

Comment: You can remove all code related to `$filelist`, `$files` and `$prefix` and just iterate through `$data` directly when adding files. I would also recommend that you check the paths properly. You're currently allowing anyone to define what ever file they want on the server (as long as the web server user can read it).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson & ArtisticPhoenix  Thanks a ton bro. it worked for me. :). the foreach loop was showing an error. I placed $data= explode(',', $data); before that.